# Does the CAP theorem imply that ACID is not possible for distributed databases?

Tags: database, nosql, distributed-computing, distributed-transactions, acid

There are [NoSQL ACID (distributed) databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608103/is-there-any-nosql-that-is-acid-compliant), despite CAP theorem. How this is possible? What's the relation between CAP theorem and (possible/not possible of) being ACID?

> Is **impossible** for a distributed computer system to simultaneously provide consistency,
>   availability and partition tolerance.

Answer (score 12):

CAP theorem is actually a bit misleading. The fact you can have a CA design is nonsense because when a partition occurs you necessarily have a problem regarding consistency (data synchronization issue for example) or availability (latency). That's why there is a more accurate theorem stating that :

During a *partition* in a distributed system, you must chose between **consistency** and **availability**.

Still in practice it is not that simple. You should note that the choice between consistency and availability isn't binary. You can even have some degree of both. For example regarding ACID, you can have atomic and durable transactions with NoSQL, but forfeit a degree of isolation and consistency for better availability. Availability can then be assimilated to latency because your response time will depend on several factors (is the nearest server available ?).

So, to answer your question, this is usually marketing bullshit. You need to actually scratch the surface to see what the solution is exactly gaining and forfeiting.

If you want deeper explanations you can look [here](http://www.infoq.com/articles/cap-twelve-years-later-how-the-rules-have-changed), [here](http://blogs.the451group.com/information_management/2011/12/14/newsql-cap-theorem-and-latency-tolerance/) or [here](http://www.bailis.org/blog/when-is-acid-acid-rarely/).

Comment: Thank you for this good answer! I have additional question too: If we choose availability, it means that we prefer to have speed - In the other words, if we have communication problem (partition),  nodes are again online but they are not sync. Or if we prefer (consistency) exact data - for instance if we have transactions of million euros and etc... At this case we will chose consistency. Am I correct? 

What theorem is that? does it have any name?  :)

Comment: @grep Yes you're correct but you wouldn't do that because there's too much trade-offs choosing one or the other. Real world is more complicated than a theorem :)

Comment: Thank you again.
Using CAP theorem, I know which database are between CP (BigData, Mongo, Hbase) and which is between AP (Riak,Cassandra, Dynamo).

If we use new theorem,  consistency or availability how to choose database? If we will sad that does BigData, Mongo, Hbase have only consistency and Dynamo, Riak, Cassandra have only Availabillity, will this be correct? As I understand this is not correct, I can have both of them with some degree. is it true?

Comment: @grep I can't claim I know all of them but yes it's true.

Answer (score 3):

The [PACELC theorem extends CAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PACELC_theorem) to talk about the tradeoffs even when partitions aren't happening. One of the exciting insights for distributed systems, is that they can be made partition tolerant without losing consistency, when consensus protocols such as RAFT or Paxos are used to create a transaction log. [The Calvin protocol](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/5/23/paper-calvin-fast-distributed-transactions-for-partitioned-d.html) combines a RAFT log with deterministic transaction application.

[FaunaDB](https://fauna.com/blog/consistency-without-clocks-faunadb-transaction-protocol) implements Calvin, allowing it to maintain ACID transactions with strict-serializability, even during partitions or during replica failure, as long as a quorum of replicas is not partitioned.