# How do I design a scalable data storage system for big billion sale?

Tags: database, scalable, bigdata

The system should provide ACID guarantees.
I have to work on this project during my Database course. I don't know where to start. Any help would be useful.

Comment: Be careful if you consider NOSQL. Although you can make a NOSQL db ACID compliant  they generally don't. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608103/is-there-any-nosql-that-is-acid-compliant

Answer (score 0):

Start with the right hardware.  No database runs quickly or reliably with slow or unreliable hardware.  I recommend NetApp systems for data that needs absolute guarantees of speed, reliability, quick recovery, and fail-safe backups.

As for the rest of the design -- what version of SQL is covered in your course?